# How to read CSV file without caring delimiter and create data frame with Azure Databricks(Python)?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I would have CSV file. I would like to read entire row (as single string) and parse string and create data frame with columns and then save CSV file. Reason is that there is encoding issues in CSV file and cannot read it properly. How to read CSV as single column? How to parse based on pipes and colons and form data frame?

Shape123|"MULTIPOLYGON (((496000 6908000, 495000 6908000, 495000 6909000, 496000 6909000, 496000 6908000)))"|"Red"|"Long"|"208336"|"5"|"-1"

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file as a series of the text lines, not use the CSV as input format:

```
df = spark.read.text(path_to_file)
```

this will create a dataframe with one column named `value`, and then you can do with it whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the file with
`df = spark.read.format('csv').load('{FILE_PATH}')` 
If there is an encoding issue on any line, the spark will automatically add a '_corrupted_record' column which contains the whole line as a string and null in other columns. Then you could filter corrupted lines and use `udf` to delimit and fix issue.